# How do asp.net core universal proxy

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I`m do proxy service in asp.net core, extensions where the request will be routed to another service.

My extension:

```
 public static IApplicationBuilder UseProxy(this IApplicationBuilder builder, List<ProxySetting> options)
    {
        builder.Use(async (context, next) =>
        {
            var resultPathHandler = options.ProxySettingHandler(context.Request.Path, context.Request.Method);

            if (!resultPathHandler.Equal)
                //continues through the rest of the pipeline
                await next();
            else
            {
                using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
                {
                    var pathSetting = resultPathHandler.Setting;
                    var requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage();

                    //добавляем хедеры
                    foreach (var header in context.Request.Headers)
                    {
                        if (!httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation(header.Key, header.Value.ToArray()))
                        {
                            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation(header.Key,
                                header.Value.ToArray());
                        }
                    }


                    if (context.Request.HasFormContentType && context.Request.Form.Count > 0)
                    {
                        var temp = new Dictionary<string, object>();
                        foreach (var form in context.Request.Form)
                        {
                            requestMessage.Properties.Add(form.Key, form.Value);
                            temp.Add(form.Key, form.Value);
                        }
                        var jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(temp).Replace(":[", ":").Replace("],",",");

                        var mediatype = string.Empty;
                        if (context.Request.ContentType.Contains(';'))
                            mediatype = context.Request.ContentType.Split(';')[0];
                        else
                            mediatype = context.Request.ContentType;

                        requestMessage.Content = new StringContent(jsonString, Encoding.UTF8, mediatype);
                    }

                    requestMessage.Headers.Host = pathSetting.Host;
                    var host = pathSetting.GetUri(context.Request.Path);
                    var uriString = $"{host}{context.Request.QueryString}";
                    requestMessage.RequestUri = new Uri(uriString);
                    requestMessage.Method = new HttpMethod(pathSetting.Method);
                    var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(requestMessage);
                    var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    var resultObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<object>(result);
                    context.Response.StatusCode = (int)response.StatusCode;
                    await context.Response.WriteAsync(resultObj.ToString());
                }
            }
        });

        return builder;
    }
```

where this code:

```
                if (context.Request.HasFormContentType && context.Request.Form.Count > 0)
                {
                    var temp = new Dictionary<string, object>();
                    foreach (var form in context.Request.Form)
                    {
                        requestMessage.Properties.Add(form.Key, form.Value);
                        temp.Add(form.Key, form.Value);
                    }
                    var jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(temp).Replace(":[", ":").Replace("],",",");

                    var mediatype = string.Empty;
                    if (context.Request.ContentType.Contains(';'))
                        mediatype = context.Request.ContentType.Split(';')[0];
                    else
                        mediatype = context.Request.ContentType;

                    requestMessage.Content = new StringContent(jsonString, Encoding.UTF8, mediatype);
                }
```

Add to content post and put parameters, with application/x-www-form-urlencoded or application/form-data, and send to other service, but i dont get this parameters in other service.
Help me, need release this feature. Thx and sorry for my bad English

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to to reinvent the wheel. ASP.NET Core already has and provides own [ProxyMiddleware](https://github.com/aspnet/Proxy/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Proxy/ProxyMiddleware.cs).